# Mongoose: Populating without ref in parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my node.js + mongoose application I have a parent and a child schema which have the refs of each other:

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
  , age     : Number
  , stories : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var StorySchema = new Schema({
    _creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
  , title    : String
  , fans     : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});
```

Now I am able to populate all stories when fetching a person by:

```
Person.findOne({ name: "some name"}).populate('stories').exec(...);
```

Recently I recognized that a growing array like stories in person slows down the performance for **huge** arrays. So I want to change that, because in my case the array is growing really fast and gets huge. My solution appeared to be easy. I changed the person schema to

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
  , age     : Number
});
```

that only the StorySchema holds the ref.

Now the question: Is there a way or workaround to populate even so the stories in my person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do:

```
var Script = mongoose.model('Script');  
Person.findOne({ name: "some name" }, function(err, person) {
    Script.find({ _creator: person._id }, function(err, scripts) {
        person.scripts = scripts;
        ...
    })
})
```

Hope that might helped.

Comment: @user1189762 did this help any?

Comment: Yes, but then it is not possible to sort or filter by script length etc...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the new feature "Populate Virtuals", it will make your life easier