# Mongoose populate without ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Is there anyway to populate a query without the field being `ref`'ed in the schema?

I have something like this:

```
var ParentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    childProperty: String
});

var ChildSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    property: String
});
```

Then I export the models as `Parent` and `Child`, respectively. Also note that even though I didn't add it for simplicity, both `childProperty` and `property` fields are unique, just not ObjectIds.

And I'm trying this:

```
Parent.findOne({})
      .populate({
          path: "childProperty",
          select: "name",
          model: "Child",
          match: {"property": "this.childProperty"},
          options: null
      })
      .exec(function(err, foundParent){
          (...)
          console.log(foundParent);
          (...)
      });
```

But all I get when I `console.log(foundParent)` is `childProperty: null`.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Can anyone share some insight?

Comment: I don't think you will get some collection without referencing it http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: check this answer it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721090/mongoose-populating-without-ref-in-parent

Comment: @santhosh Thank you for your suggestion. I had already seen that answer but it didn't help me much. According to the docs it should be possible... http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate